# Divisor sums over values of binary forms of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sums-of-squares, prime-number-theorem

Let $\tau$ be the divisor function, that is 
$$
\tau(n)=\sharp\{d \in \mathbb{N}, d|n\}.
$$

I was wondering if anyone has ever proved an asymptotic estimate
for the sum
$$S(x):=\sum_{p,q\leq x}\tau(p^2+q^2),$$
where the summation is taken over pairs of primes.

One obviously expects $$S(x)\sim c\frac{x^2}{\log x}$$ as $x \to \infty,$
where $c$ is a positive constant which is an infinite product of Euler factors.

This is based on the heuristic that each of the $\pi(x)^2$
terms present in $S(x)$ is approximated by a constant multiple 
of
$\log x$ on average.

Brun-Titchmarsch and Bombieri-Vinogradov 
can be used to prove the upper and the lower bound
$$ 
c\frac{x^2}{\log x} (\frac{1}{2}+o(1))
\leq S(x) \leq 
c\frac{x^2}{\log x} (2+o(1)),
$$ as $x\to \infty$ respectively.

But the question remains, $\textit{can we prove an asymptotic?}$

Comment: Actually, I have a different related question. By Fouvry and Iwaniec, we know that $a^2+p^2$ is infinitely often prime. Can we show the same for $p^2+q^2$, that it is infinitely often twice a prime?

Comment: It seems to me that the large sieve could be used to prove such an asymptotic formula, but you'd have to check the details.

Comment: NAME_IN_CAPS It is possible to obtain an "almost prime" result for $p^2+q^2$ but obtaining 2*prime is harder than $x^2+1=p$.

Comment: @Lucia: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Possibly simpler questions would be $$\sum\tau(x^2+y^2)$$ over all $x,y$ up to $n$ (so, not restricting $x,y$ to primes), or $$\sum\tau(p+1)$$ summing over primes $p<n$. Are asymptotics known for these?

Comment: Getting ready for the Big Push, Darling?

Comment: @Gerry: Computing asymptotics for the partial sums of $\tau(p+a)$, with $a$ fixed, is known as the Titchmarsh divisor problem. This was solved by Linnik, but nowadays can be done by the Brun--Titchmarsh and Bombieri--Vinogradov theorems. 

As for $\tau(x^2+y^2)$, it's maybe more natural to consider the sum extended over all pairs $x,y$ with $x^2+y^2 \le n$. That can be attacked by applying a mean-vale theorem of Wirsing to the function $n\mapsto \tau(n) r(n)$, where $r(n) = \frac{1}{4} \#\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=n\}$. (Note that $r$ is multiplicative.)

Comment: @so-called friend Don:  I am terribly sorry to inform you that providing an asymptotic for $$\sum \tau(x^2+y^2)$$ is manifestly not untrivial. The hyperbola trick and lattice point counting in regions of $\mathbb{R}^2$ provide an asymptotic with a square root error saving. Wirsing's theorem (or any good old form of contour integration) is sadly only the last, and most technically undemanding, step in this approach. When this argument is adopted to the form $p^2+q^2$,  we are provided with the lower bound stated in the question but I am not sure if one can obviously get something better.

Comment: @CaptainDarling: The asymptotic for $\sum_{n\leq x}\tau(n)r(n)$ is easy to get by Mellin inversion, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)r(n)n^{-s}=\zeta(s)^2L(s,\chi_4)^2/L(2s,\chi_4)$. Perhaps you thought the same, but I found the wording "manifestly not untrivial" slightly confusing: did you mean "manifestly trivial"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly not the opposite of what I thought.

Answer (score 4):

An answer regarding the use of large sieve suggested by Lucia (too long for a comment).

I guess her/his thought was along the following lines:

The divisors $d$ of $p^2+q^2$ are of order $x^2$ and the hyperbola trick reduces to estimating sums of the form $$\sum_{d\leq x}\sum_{\lambda^2=-1 (d)} \sum_{\substack{p,q \leq x \\ p= \lambda q (d)}} 1. $$ Inserting multiplicative characters in the sum over primes we will be left with an error term coming from the primitive characters, which looks like 
$$
\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}
\sum^*_{\chi(d)}
\sum_{\lambda^2=-1(d)}\overline{\chi(\lambda)}
\ \Big|
\sum_{p\leq x}\chi(p)\Big|^2 ,$$ 
which behaves as
$$\frac{1}{x}
\sum_{d\leq x}\tau(d)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}
\sum^*_{\chi(d)}
\ \Big|
\sum_{p\leq x}\chi(p)\Big|^2.$$
Ideally we would like to show that this is $o(x^2/\log x)$.
However the large sieve in the form of
[Th.4,p.g. 160, multiplicative Davenport]
gives a bound for this quantity which is of order $O(x^2)$
and is therefore inadequate. Essentially this is the level of distribution problem.

What we described can show that the contribution of $d\leq x/(\log x)^A$ to the sums with primitive characters is indeed $o(x^2/\log x)$ for an appropriate value of $A>0$ but I am not sure whether the micro logarithmic savings coming from Hooley's-Delta function can be used to say something about the remaining range.

Comment: You're right; this is what I had in mind.  But the range between $x/(\log x)^A$ and $x$ is problematic.  But then in your question you state an upper bound for $S(x)$ which is not clear to me  -- Brun-Titchmarsh doesn't seem to imply the bound, and one is off by a $\log \log x$ factor I think.  (Because B-T would save only a factor of $\log (ex/d)$ and this is problematic for the large $d$.)

Comment: Also, the large sieve argument would give the right asymptotic as a lower bound.  (Note that you also have to use Siegel-Walfisz for small values of $d$; the large  sieve works in the range $(\log x)^A \le d \le x/(\log x)^A$.

Answer (score 2):

When computing e.g. an asymptotic for $\sum_{p\leq x}d(p-1)$ you would like to estimate the number of primes $p$ such that $n$ divides $p-1$ by the prime number theorem as $\sim\frac{x}{\varphi(n)\log x}$. We do not know GRH, so we can't use this estimate for all $n<x^{1/2-\epsilon}$, but we do have Bombieri-Vinogradov, so we can use this estimate for almost all $n$ in the relevant range.

This approach does not work here, since for $\sum d(p^2+q^2)$ we have to take $n$ as large as $x^{1-\epsilon}$, however, the distribution of $p^2+q^2$ is a lot nicer than the distribution of $p$. So instead of a non-trivial bound for $\max_a\left|\pi(x, a, n) - \frac{x}{\varphi(n)\log x}\right|$ it suffices to bound 
$$
\sum_{a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{n}} \pi(x,a,n)\pi(x, b, n) - \frac{x^2}{\varphi(n)^2\log^2 x}\sum_{a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{n}} 1
$$
for almost all $n$. Since we are now averaging over $a, b$, we should be able to avoid Bombieri-Vinogradov but use the Barban-Davenport-Halberstam theorem, which is applicable to all $n$ up to $x/\log^A x$, which suffices.

Filling in the detail will probably be quite some work, but I guess that two or three pages of Cauchy-Schwarz and character calculations should do the trick.

Comment: Dear JCSP, this is indeed helpful. But what is to be done with the remaining moduli $x/\log^Ax<n<x$?

Comment: For this range an upper bound sieve should suffice. The real quantity is smaller than the main term by a factor $\frac{\log x}{\log\log x}$, so loosing a constant does not matter. Hence we can replace the set of primes e.g. by all integers having only prime factors $\geq x^{0.01}$. To do so by Selbergs sieve you need asymptotics for the number of solutions of $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, $a,b,\leq x$, $q|ab$, where $n$ and $q$ satisfy $n<x$, $q<$x^{0.02}$, which looks doable.